# Virus scanner triggering my inotify process

Tags: linux

We have inotify setup looking for changes/creation of files in a directory. It then SFTP's the file somewhere. We are using IN_CLOSE_WRITE, but our anti-virus scanner triggers this on existing files when it opens them to scan.
Should I switch to IN_MODIFY, or something else? Curious how to prevent scans from triggering it, other than to not scan that directory.

Comment: Not scanning that directory sounds like a very workable solution.  But you might also ask your AV vendor if they really need to open files *for writing* when scanning.

Comment: Thanks John. I think we are going to try moving the files to a different folder after they are sent out so that the monitored folder won't have any files in it, except new ones until they are sent. Appreciate the feedback.